# Staircase Problem - understanding the basic logic

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Here is the recursive version of the staircase problem (There are N stairs, a person standing at the bottom wants to reach the top. The person can climb either 1 stair, 2 stairs or 3 stairs at a time. Count the number of different ways the person can reach the top.)

```
public static int findStep(int n) 
    { 
        if (n == 1 || n == 0)  
            return 1; 
        else if (n == 2)  
            return 2; 

        else
            return findStep(n - 3) +  
                   findStep(n - 2) + 
                   findStep(n - 1);     
    }
```

**My question is, why we are returning 1 when n=0 ??**

To me, n=0 means there are no more stairs so it should return 0, but if I do so then the program doesn't work for other non-zero inputs. I saw similar questions in this site but non of those explain why we are returning 1 when there are no more stairs.

Comment: I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code `n=0` means in the last step `n` was equal to `1`or `2` or `3`. in other words :

`n-1=0` which means in the last step `n=1`, so there is one way to reach the top of stairs.

`n-3=0` which means in the last step `n=3`, so one way to reach the top of stairs is to make `3` steps.

Comment: This is incorrect. If we call `findStep(0)`, the last step was neither 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Yes, if you call the method with 0 initially (no stair), it will return the wrong result. What I did, I check n for 0 before I call the method. This way it will answer correctly always.

Answer (score 2):

This is a selection problem. Think of the recurrence as the number of ways to select and order a combination of zero or more 1's, zero or more 2's, and zero or more 3's, that will together sum to `n`. There is only one way to make such a selection for `n = 0`: select none.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, why we are returning 1 when n=0 ??

It means, there is only one possible way to reach 1st stair. You can understand more about it by going through https://medium.com/trick-the-interviwer/the-staircase-problem-9840b11201a5